# excel regex macro to match zip code and move it four columns to the right

Tags: regex, excel, vba

I'm working with a big excel file that has a lot of information on businesses my company works with. I just imported another large excel file and their was a difference in format. The larger file we already have has the address, state and zip code in separate columns each spaced two apart like so:

[image]

I didn't make this spreadsheet or else I wouldn't have put the columns like that, but thats how the lady that works with it likes it.

The problem is that the sheet I imported has the city, state, and zip info all in the same cell like this:

> Trollville, NY 12345

I have already over the states since 99% of the new ones were all the same state which a quick find and replace all worked. I'm now left with this

> Trollville 12345

I want to move that zip code four columns to the right into the proper cell. I wrote a basic regex but don't know much about excel-vba since I haven't used it in years, but this is what I've come up with. I just don't know how to tell vba to print output the matches (which I made into an array) into the appropriate column. This is what I have so far:

```
Function findZipCode(zipCode)
     Dim regEx As New VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp
     Dim matches, s
     regEx.Pattern = "\s\d{5}\W"
     regEx.Global = True
     s = ""
     If regEx.Test(zipCode) Then
         Set matches = regEx.Execute(zipCode)
         For Each Match In matches
             s = s & Match.Value

         Next
         findZipCode = s
     Else
         findZipCode = ""
     End If
End Function
```

What do I need to add? I'm open to alternative methods too if there is an easier way to do this.

Thanks in advance for the advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you use the in-built Excel Worksheet Functions?

Place this in target column `=RIGHT(A2,5)` would capture the rightmost 5 characters of your string iff they are numeric. This will work if all of your values data values have a 5-digit zip codes at the end.

Alternatively, you could wrap it with a conditional such as `IF(ISNUMBER(VALUE(RIGHT(A2,5))),RIGHT(A2,5),"")`, whcih would add a layer of validation to the process.

Also, did you know there is an option that may do this for you automatically if your data is comma (or space) delimited `Data ribbon->Text to columns`

Comment: No, it would capture the rightmost 5 characters of your string but if your data always has a 5-digit zip codes it would work. You could wrap it with a conditional such as `=IF(ISNUMBER(VALUE(RIGHT(A2,5))),RIGHT(A2,5),"")`

Comment: ohhh I got it, does this work with only letters then, so I can remove the numbers?

Comment: `=LEFT(A2,FIND(",",A2)-1)` would match everything before the comma (might fall over if there are multiple commas but there are ways around that too using the text functions)

Comment: the simple command you used in the answer worked fine, just need to remove those numbers from the original column now

Comment: oh man I wish I had known about that text to columns option before I started taking the stuff out

Comment: You can take the remainder with something like `=TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A2,E2,""),",",""))` where `E2` is the zipcode - this will remove all commas and remove remaining whitespace from either side of your string